# how to restore a my.ini file?

Tags: mysql

I changed the application to open the my.ini file by the command "open with".
Now my my.ini file is unreadable (no newline) and the mysqld service cannot start.
Is it possible to restore the file ?

Comment: open notepad, file -> open, select "all files" from the file type combobox, navigate to my.ini and open it, correct contents, save.

Comment: Thank you but no success for me. The mysql service doesn't exist anymore (i am on windows) !

Comment: If the file is missing then you will have to recreate it.

Comment: The file is not missing. When I try to start or stop mysql, I have the following message: the requested pause, continue, or stop is not valid for this service.

Comment: You might have to reinstall it.  Sounds like you broke something

Comment: You are right. I try instrsrv mysql remove but it requests to stop mysql before. And net stop mysql cannot be executed !!

Comment: Try restarting, then reinstalling.  I can't use the chat service from work.

Comment: I killed the service in the registry !!

Comment: With what program did you open my.ini ???

Comment: with the wordpad program

Comment: Now I can create the service but it doesn't start because of the my.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never EVER use the registry to manually remove programs.  Your only hope is to uninstall mysql and reinstall it.  If you encounter issues with that, you may need to contact customer support.

If you made a backup of the registry before changing it, restore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you messed up the registry, you may not be able to get MySQL reinstalled using MSI

However, not all hope is lost.

When it comes to Windows, I hate MSI installation with a passion. I always download the no-install zip file instead. Back on Feb 10, 2011, I wrote up a [**ServerFault post on how to configure a no-install MySQL setup**](https://serverfault.com/a/234125/69271).

With regard to the my.ini, maybe you can use another text editor that can read Linux/Unix based files. [I sometimes use the Windows version of `vi` to read Linux files in Windows](http://www.winvi.de/winvi302.zip). See if you can use WinVi to open the my.ini.